# My non-EU husband working and staying in Ireland?

Tags: immigration, eu-citizens, ireland

I am an Irish citizen. I got married to non-EU citizen. We got marriage certificate done in Ukraine. We applied for joint visa (irish nat. spouse) and got a refusal due to not been employed 3 years prior to application. I am 18 years and it's my first time working.

- Do I need to work and wait 3 years in order to have my husband with me in Ireland?
- Is there a chance of him getting a short-stay visa and apply for residence card (eu1)?
- Will he have a right to work with that certificate or only be able to stay with me for longer then 3 months?

Comment: You may have an easier time getting your husband to live with you if you move to another EU country.  Under EU rules, there's no 3-year limit as there apparently is under Irish rules, but you do have to make enough money to support yourself and your husband.  After you've lived in the other EU country for 6 months, you should be eligible to move back to Ireland under the EU rules instead of the Irish rules.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Movement_of_Citizens_Directive for more information.

Comment: @phoog That's a good tip but actually having enough money to support your family is only required *if you don't work*. If you work, your rights are (perhaps counter-intuitvely) more extensive, the only requirement is that the work be “effective and genuine” and previous court cases have ruled, e.g. that  a contract for 8 hours a week was enough (even if you earn very little money and are eligible for all kinds of benefits/tax credits).